Reference Tabs in excel from a list
I have a budget summary sheet that summarizes values on a month worksheet using sumif. Example "=SUMIF(June!H6:H129,$C39,June!D6:D129)". Instead of referencing "june", I would like to have a drop down list of months in L1 and the formula would refeence that month selected would then return the values. Each tab is a month.
I tried
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$L$1&"'!A2:A125"),Credit!C3,INDIRECT("'"&$L$1&"'!D2:D125"))

and it did not work.

Try: =SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$L$1&"!H6:H129"),$C39,INDIRECT("'"&$L$1&"!D6:D129"))
